# Qt Application state lifecycle

Tags: c++, qt

I begin with Qt and something is not clear to me with the application state. I use Qt 5.5. I'm currently learning on Windows, but Android devices is the next step, hence my attention to application state.

I have created my own `QApplication`-derived class, I have registered the `applicationStateChanged` signal. I have guessed that I should persist part of my configuration when `applicationStateChanged` is signaled. I presume I'll have to use `Qt.labs.settings` as well as I want to use QML.

Obviously, I'm wrong with several things.
First of all, I do not receive any `Qt::ApplicationSuspended` message.
I have overrided to `QApplication::event(e)` in order to see if I missed a signal, and it seems that only `Quit` event is sent.

```cpp
QML debugging is enabled. Only use this in a safe environment.
void LAACApplication::event(QEvent *e = QEvent(LanguageChange, 0x28fd00) )
void LAACApplication::event(QEvent *e = QEvent(DynamicPropertyChange, 0x28fcbc) )
void LAACApplication::event(QEvent *e = QEvent(LanguageChange, 0x28fa70) )
void LAACApplication::event(QEvent *e = QEvent(ApplicationActivate, 0x28daf4) )
void LAACApplication::event(QEvent *e = QApplicationStateChangeEvent(ApplicationActive) )
void LAACApplication::onApplicationStateChanged(Qt::ApplicationState state = Qt::ApplicationState(ApplicationActive) )
void LAACApplication::event(QEvent *e = QEvent(Quit, 0x1fd88cc8) )
void LAACApplication::event(QEvent *e = QEvent(LanguageChange, 0x28fca0) )
```

Or maybe I should look into `QApplication::commitData()` as stated [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/session.html) in order to perform such tasks ?

So, to make it short : how should I handle application state changes with Qt ?

Here is my code :

**`laacapplication.h`**

```cpp
#ifndef LAACAPPLICATION_H
#define LAACAPPLICATION_H

#include <QApplication>

class LAACApplication : public QApplication
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit LAACApplication(int &argc, char **argv);


public slots:
    void onApplicationStateChanged(Qt::ApplicationState state);

protected:
    bool event(QEvent * e);

private:
    void readSettings();
    void writeSettings();
};

#endif // LAACAPPLICATION_H
```

**`laacapplication.cpp`** (fragments)

```
void LAACApplication::onApplicationStateChanged(Qt::ApplicationState state)
{
    qDebug() << "void LAACApplication::onApplicationStateChanged(Qt::ApplicationState state =" << state << ")";
    if (Qt::ApplicationSuspended == state)
       writeSettings();
}

bool LAACApplication::event(QEvent *e)
{
    qDebug() << "void LAACApplication::event(QEvent *e =" << e << ")";
    return QApplication::event(e);
}
```

**`main.cpp`**

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    LAACApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));

    QObject::connect(&app, SIGNAL(applicationStateChanged(Qt::ApplicationState)), &app, SLOT(onApplicationStateChanged(Qt::ApplicationState)));

    return app.exec();
}
```

By the way, I did not succeed in using automatic connection between my signal and my slot therefore there is an explicit call to `QObject::connect()`.

Comment: (from the edit queue re [this edit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/13526506)) convention here is to put no space between the end of a sentence and the corresponding question mark. I've improved your edit to remove those spaces, figured it might be useful for you to know why.

Answer (score 3):

Define "Application State". On Desktop Platforms, the state indicates whether you application has focus or not, see [`Qt::ApplicationState`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#ApplicationState-enum) for details. (For example, it will loose focus if you select another window). These state changes should work, at least they do for me. They have nothing to do with the applications "life-cycle" (like on Android). If you want to do something as soon as your program quits, do it in your `main` or use the [`QCoreApplication::aboutToQuit`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#aboutToQuit) signal.

For desktop applications, you would ignore the state in most cases. Saving settings for example can be done before your application quits, with one of the methods mentioned above. On Android, however it's different. (See [Android Activity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) for more Details. Even if you create a C++-Qt application, the life-cycle still applies). As far as I know, those changes in the Activity-State are **not** passed on to the application, but I never actually tested it. If you need it, you can always implement it yourself using native java code. Please note, that even if you aren't notified of those changes, they still will occure, i.e. your application will stop executing (and resume wherever it stopped as soon as the application gets it focus back).

**Long short story:**
 On Desktop platforms, your application will start, run and eventually terminate without ever beeing actually paused (Under normal circumstances). Saving settings is only required at the end of the program.
On Android, "minimizing" the application will pause it, but this is done automatically.

Are you using `QSettings`? Try to store changes there as soon as they are made, and you don't have to be afraid of data loss.

And regarding your connect problem: connections are **NOT** done automatically. There is a function called [`QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetaobject.html#connectSlotsByName) that tries to create a name based connection. It gets called automatically if you are using a ui-Based Widget class inside of the `setupUi` function.

Comment: Thanks. My question is about correctly using the Qt framework interpretation of an application state lifecycle. My guess is that Qt is desgined to answer real-life problems conveniently. Including problems I'm not aware of. To benefit from this work I have to use Qt framework correctly. For instance, I've coded a tiny prototype with Java on Android and I had to handle application state. What is done "automatically" with my transient data during a calculation ? What messages should I catch for an application targetting both Desktop and Android ?

Comment: Well, it's not that easy - either you let Qt handle the application states (and you just don't care what happens with your data - cause it works), or you implement plattform specifiy solutions by yourself. I would recommend the first one until you explicitly need special behavior